# java voice command

Tags: java, nlp, awtrobot

I'm still pretty new to java and I was thinking about making a program where the computer could listen to you talking and write what you said on word or something using the java Robot. Honestly, I have no idea where to start with this and could really use some help on this. Also, I was looking around on my computer and noticed that it does have a voice engine of some sort, is there a way I could implement that into my program?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Haha! Good joke man! Two choices: wait for Google's voice detection, or work for them.

Comment: Voice recognition is *extremely* complex.  (Put another way, if it could be easily done [or even difficultly done], wouldn't be all be dictating to Word by now instead of typing?)

Comment: Good point...I have just been looking for some project to do in my down time and saw a few posts about the same thing but they didn't really help me out. But is there a way I could use a third party's voice recconition and or voice engine in my program instead of writing one?

Comment: In all honesty, this may not be the best project for a relative beginner! Anything where you have to start interfacing with things outside Java adds a whole set of dragons that will distract you from actually learning core Java. I would be tempted to pick another project to start with such as maybe a simple logic game, or some little tool to help you with some small task...?

Comment: ya, I think I will take your advice...thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to tap into your dictation software's facilities and hook them into your Java program, then start by taking a look at the JavaSpeech API or the Microsoft Speech API along with the Java Native Interface (JNI). The latter isn't a simple project for a beginner. The former, if your dictation software is compatible, could be something in the order of a few weeks of work for a relative beginner.

For making the dictated speech appear in Word or other external program, it's not clear to me where your Java program would fit in here: your dictation software will natively provide the facility of dictating to whatever the currently active window is, presumably.

Comment: Thanks Neil, Ill keep that in mind, I think I will start with something a little less complex and see if I can build up to this.

Answer (score 0):

Speech Recognition is a complex programming to understand. as you are a beginner go head and see Sphinx4 for recognition written entirely in java and FreeTTS as Synthesizer written entirely in java. first make a simpler recognizer then you can think of Dictation using JNI